# Execution behaviour of Codeigniter classes

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using MY_Controller to handle login functionality, problem is I don't know how to stop MY_Controller from being extended when an AJAX request occurs. It seems redirect() will stop the child class with a non-AJAX request, is it possible to stop the child class being **executed** for an AJAX request?

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

        if(!$this->session->userdata('userid')) {
            //Render public menu in view
            $this->load->view('header_public_view');
            if($this->login_required()) {
                //Possibly change to render authentication view rather than redirect
                $this->session->set_userdata('destination', $this->input->server('REQUEST_URI'));
                redirect('authentication/login');
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($this->session->userdata('userid'));
            $this->load->view('header_user_view', $data);
        }

    }
    else {

        if(!this->session->userdata('userid') && $this->login_required) {

            //send response telling client to redirect  

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information, what do you mean stop the child class? stop it  from doing what?

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your AJAX functions into a separate controller which does not exended MY_Controller

```
function Ajax_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    //code
}
```